# using a variable instead of repeating the same action

Tags: jquery, contains, var, attr

How can you use a variable (or another way) instead of repeating the same lines/actions?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.PageMenu a:contains("Home")').attr("href","#");
$('.PageMenu a:contains("About")').attr("href","#");
$('.PageMenu a:contains("Blog")').attr("href","#");
$('.PageMenu a:contains("Contact")').attr("href","#");

</script>​
```

or is this the easiest and/or the most efficient way to do something like this?  Wondering what the best practice should be for this.  Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('.PageMenu').children('a:contains("Home"),a:contains("About"),a:contains("Blog"), a:contains("Contact")').attr("href","#");
```

Comment: I'm torn between the top two answers here, as they both work.  thanks so much for the info, this is a great idea.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it in a single line as below:

```
$('.PageMenu a:contains("Home"),.PageMenu a:contains("About"), .PageMenu a:contains("Blog"), .PageMenu a:contains("Contact")').attr("href","#");
```

Comment: I'm torn between the top two answers, as they both work.  thanks so much for the info here, this is a great concept.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked about best practice, I was just wondering if you can add a unique class to these links such as `click` and use

```
  $('.click').attr("href","#");
```

Comment: Good idea, however, in this case, I would have to write a script to insert that class into those elements.  When the menu is dynamically generated, I am stuck with another solution.  But this would work otherwise.  thanks.